# How to share variables when importing one js from different jsp?

Tags: javascript, jsp

When one javascript is imported from two jsp, we want the javascript variable to be shared.

I imported mytest.js from a.jsp.

And I imported mytest.js from b.jsp.

When a button is clicked in a.jsp, a variable in main.js is changed. However, when the variable is accessed in b.jsp, the variable is not changed.

Global variables of main.js are not shared between a.jsp and b.jsp.

How should variable sharing be handled?

Comment: try window[variable]?

Comment: sorry, don't work.